# A subgroup generated by a 4-cycles and 5-cycles in $S_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra

What is the subgroup generated by a 5-cycles and a 4-cycles in $S_5$.

I suspect this is a group of order $20$, but how do I proves this?

Comment: If you expect people to put in the effort to answer a question, then it is polite to put in some effort yourself. For example, simply telling us where you got the problem from or explaining what you tried would be a big step forward! (For further feedback/help with asking questions, you can ask [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback).)

Comment: @user1729 I am sorry, I figured out the answer immediately after I posted the question, so I decided to close it. I tried do delete my question but someone already posted a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(4321)\cdot(12345)=(45)$, and you can get any other 2-cycle in the similar way. So all 2-cycles belong to this subgroup, and thus it is the whole $S_5$.